# Using Variables inside one another Bash

Tags: bash, loops, export

I am running a for loop that calls in a variable from another file:

```
hostnames.txt
```

The variables in that file look like this:

```
export HOSTNAME_0=<hostname>
export HOSTNAME_1=<hostname>
export HOSTNAME_2=<hostname>
```

I am trying use them inside a for loop like this:

```
. hostnames.txt
for f in {0..10}; do
ssh $HOSTNAME_'{$f}'
if [$? !=0]; then
   echo "Unable to SSH to server $HOSTNAME_'{$f}'"
   exit 1
fi
```

However its not reading the value correctly, and I'm not sure what I'm missing. Would love any help.

Comment: Check your spacing inside the [ ], or maybe use (( ))

Answer (score 3):

You need to build your variable name and access it with `${!var}`, e.g.:

```
. hostnames.txt
for f in {0..10}; do
  hostnamevar=HOSTNAME_${f}
  ssh ${!hostnamevar}
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Unable to SSH to server ${!hostnamevar}"
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

Comment: You need spaces in the `if` test expression: `if [ $? != 0 ]; then`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I was merely copying his code which wasn’t relevant IMO. Anyways I’ve edited the answer so as to fix the rest of his code too.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I have an additional question though, I have additional commands I want to execute on the remote server after I've logged in and now none of them are running. Any idea how do actually get them to run?

Comment: @user2019182 Since this looks like a different issue, please open another thread.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't have other vars starting with "HOSTNAME", you can use

```
    . hostnames.txt
    for host in $(set | sed -n '/^HOSTNAME*=/ s/[^=]*=//p') ; do
       ssh "${host}"
       # or, for calling 2 commands:
       # ssh "${host}" "echo 1 2 3; echo 4"
       if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
          echo "Unable to SSH to server ${host}"
          exit 1
       fi
    done
```